# Simulate TAB or SPACE keypress from the inside of a Qt application

Tags: c++, windows, qt

The aim is to select and click widgets (just like the user can do with TAB and SPACE key strokes) of a Qt application from a second application. Both applications are on the same network and "talk" by the mean of QTcpSocket but it's not the problem.
So, the 2nb application can be seen as a 3 pushbuttons panel (TAB, shift TAB and SPACE) that should control the 1st application. This 1st application can also be used directly like any other Qt application.
From the inside of the 1st application, and on reception of an adequat message, I tried to send a keypress event but nothing happens :

```
void Appli1::onAppli2_TabClickedMessage()
{
    QKeyEvent keyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Tab, Qt::NoModifier);
    QCoreApplication::sendEvent((QObject*)appli1.MainWindow(), &keyEvent);
}
```

I suppose this is not the correct way to do. I verified that I execute this slot within debugger but nothing happens, just like events go to the infinite void ...

Any help (method or idea) appreciated

Comment: The code you have should work. The only thing that seems weird is this cast `(QObject*) appli1.MainWindow()`, it shouldn't be needed. Also, you generally shouldn't use C-style cast in C++.

Comment: I just had a look into [`QCoreApplication::sendEvent()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#sendEvent). Your sample looks correct. How do you think `MainWindow()` will process this key event? Try to send a "printable" key to e.g. a `QLineEdit`. Though, how it reacts to key presses if it doesn't have the focus? (I never tried this.) May be, derive a widget from `QWidget` with overloaded `keyPressEvent()` to use it as receiver. So, you can easily confirm that your sent key event arrives.

Comment: You cannot fake input like that, particularly with a Qt application that has notoriously unreliable input handling. Try using UI Automation, that's what it's for after all.

Comment: @Jaa-c thanks ... and you're right, it works :-)  I builded a small application and it worked ... I only has to insert a appli->processEvents() to make it visible. Subject closed

Comment: Why not sending this as self-answer? Btw. I solved your issue by switching to `postEvent`.

Comment: I still have problem with the SPACE key ... I will check UI automation then ... thanx all

Comment: @ Sceff  I used postEvent in a first try but this crashed my "real" application then I tried sendEvent instead to make it work

Comment: The doc. mentions explicitly that events sent by `postEvent()` _must be allocated_ (as event loop takes ownership). This brought me to my concerns about involved (or not) event loop...

Answer (score 1):

IInspectable mentioned that the proper way for what OP intends is to use [UIAutomation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms726294.aspx). (Of course, this is assuming that OP develops on MS Windows but there are surely similar solutions for other OSes / Windows systems.)

---

Out of curiosity, I played a bit with it.

My receiver is a `QLineEdit` and the one and only widget – it gets the focus after start.

However, I didn't get it working. Other ideas I had:

- send `QKeyPress` and `QKeyRelease` symmetrically
- provide the `QString` argument in `QKeyEvent` which OP left out

but this didn't help.

Finally, I replaced `sendEvent()` with `postEvent()` as I was a bit concerned to send the event directly (aside from application event loop). Surprisingly, this works.

`testQSendEvent.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QLineEdit qEdt;
  qEdt.show();
  QTimer qTimer;
  qTimer.setInterval(1000/*ms*/);
  qTimer.start();
  int i = 0;
  QObject::connect(&qTimer, &QTimer::timeout,
    [&]() {
      qDebug() << "About to send key event for" << i;
#if 0 // 1st attempt
      { QKeyEvent keyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_0 + i, Qt::NoModifier,
          QString(QChar('0' + i)));
        QApplication::sendEvent(&qEdt, &keyEvent);
      }
      { QKeyEvent keyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease, Qt::Key_0 + i, Qt::NoModifier,
          QString(QChar('0' + i)));
        QApplication::sendEvent(&qEdt, &keyEvent);
      }
#else // 2nd attempt
      QApplication::postEvent(&qEdt,
        new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_0 + i, Qt::NoModifier,
          QString(QChar('0' + i))));
      QApplication::postEvent(&qEdt,
        new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease, Qt::Key_0 + i, Qt::NoModifier,
          QString(QChar('0' + i))));
#endif // 0
      if (++i >= 10) i = 0;
    });
  return app.exec();
}
```

`testQSendEvent.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQSendEvent.cc

QT = widgets
```

Compiled and tested in [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org):

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQSendEvent.pro

$ make

$ ./testQSendEvent
Qt Version: 5.9.4
About to send key event for 0
About to send key event for 1
About to send key event for 2
About to send key event for 3
About to send key event for 4
About to send key event for 5
About to send key event for 6
About to send key event for 7
About to send key event for 8
About to send key event for 9
About to send key event for 0
About to send key event for 1
About to send key event for 2
About to send key event for 3
About to send key event for 4
About to send key event for 5
```

[image: snapshot of testQSendEvent]

---

The modified sample with two `QLineEdit`s (where at least one of them has definitely not the focus):

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QWidget qWin;
  QVBoxLayout qVBox;
  QLineEdit qEdt1, qEdt2;
  qVBox.addWidget(&qEdt1);
  qVBox.addWidget(&qEdt2);
  qWin.setLayout(&qVBox);
  qWin.show();
  QTimer qTimer;
  qTimer.setInterval(1000/*ms*/);
  qTimer.start();
  int i = 0;
  QObject::connect(&qTimer, &QTimer::timeout,
    [&]() {
      QApplication::postEvent(&qEdt1,
        new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_0 + i, Qt::NoModifier,
        QString(QChar('0' + i))));
      QApplication::postEvent(&qEdt1,
        new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease, Qt::Key_0 + i, Qt::NoModifier,
        QString(QChar('0' + i))));
      QApplication::postEvent(&qEdt2,
        new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_A + i, Qt::NoModifier,
        QString(QChar('A' + i))));
      QApplication::postEvent(&qEdt2,
        new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease, Qt::Key_A + i, Qt::NoModifier,
        QString(QChar('A' + i))));
      if (++i >= 10) i = 0;
    });
  return app.exec();
}
```

[image: snapshot of testQSendEvent (2nd version)]

Even `QLineEdit`s which do not have the focus seem to process key events properly if directly posted to them. (I'm not sure whether this behavior depends on the Windows system. In my case, it's X11 as I tested in cygwin.)

---

As OP mentioned `QPushButton`s explicitly, I adapted my sample again:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QWidget qWin;
  QVBoxLayout qVBox;
  QPushButton qBtn1("Button 1");
  QPushButton qBtn2("Button 2");
  qVBox.addWidget(&qBtn1);
  qVBox.addWidget(&qBtn2);
  qWin.setLayout(&qVBox);
  qWin.show();
  QTimer qTimer;
  qTimer.setInterval(1000/*ms*/);
  qTimer.start();
  int i = 0;
  QObject::connect(&qTimer, &QTimer::timeout,
    [&]() {
      switch (i) {
        case 0:
          QApplication::postEvent(&qBtn1,
            new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Space, Qt::NoModifier,
              QString(QChar(' '))));
          break;
        case 1:
          QApplication::postEvent(&qBtn1,
            new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease, Qt::Key_Space, Qt::NoModifier,
              QString(QChar(' '))));
          break;
        case 2:
#if 0 // EXCLUDED
          QApplication::postEvent(&qBtn1,
            new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Tab, Qt::NoModifier,
              QString(QChar('\t'))));
          QApplication::postEvent(&qBtn1,
            new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease, Qt::Key_Tab, Qt::NoModifier,
              QString(QChar('\t'))));
#endif // 0
          break;
        case 3:
          QApplication::postEvent(&qBtn2,
            new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Space, Qt::NoModifier,
              QString(QChar(' '))));
          break;
        case 4:
          QApplication::postEvent(&qBtn2,
            new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease, Qt::Key_Space, Qt::NoModifier,
              QString(QChar(' '))));
          break;
        case 5:
#if 0 // EXCLUDED
          QApplication::postEvent(&qBtn2,
            new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Tab, Qt::NoModifier,
              QString(QChar('\t'))));
          QApplication::postEvent(&qBtn2,
            new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease, Qt::Key_Tab, Qt::NoModifier,
              QString(QChar('\t'))));
#endif // 0
          break;
      }
      if (++i > 5) i = 0;
    });
  QObject::connect(&qBtn1, &QPushButton::clicked,
    [&](bool) { qDebug() << "Button 1 clicked"; });
  QObject::connect(&qBtn2, &QPushButton::clicked,
    [&](bool) { qDebug() << "Button 2 clicked"; });
  return app.exec();
}
```

[image: snapshot of testQSendEvent (3rd version)]

Even the `QPushButton::clicked` signal was emitted:

```
$ ./testQSendEvent
Qt Version: 5.9.4
Button 1 clicked
Button 2 clicked
Button 1 clicked
Button 2 clicked
Button 1 clicked
Button 2 clicked
Button 1 clicked
```

I tried with and without focus change. (Before I `EXCLUDED` the <kbd>Tab</kbd> events, I could see the focus changing.) However, as well as in `QLineEdit` the <kbd>Space</kbd> key events are processed in `QPushButton` independently of focus.

The last sample code version, I compiled again in VS2013 with Qt 5.9.2 (for native WinAPI). It behaved *exactly* like the one I compiled in cygwin with `g++` and Qt 5.9.4 for X11.
I.e. sending <kbd>Space</kbd> key event to `QPushButton` changed its visual appearance, and the `QPushButton::clicked` signal was properly emitted.

[image: snapshot of testQEvent (3rd version) compiled with Qt/WinAPI]

---

I made "accidentally" the observation that the fourth `QString` argument of `QKeyEvent` should be set properly. I found this out when I posted

```
 QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_A + i, Qt::NoModifier,
   QString(QChar('0' + i)));
```

The receiving `QLineEdit` inserted digits obviously ignoring `Qt::Key_A + i`.

Comment: I have several widgets and I use TAB keypress event to move from one to the next widget (and shift TAB goes in reverse order) but ... SPACE keypress does not activate the pushbuttons :-(

Comment: This may have to do whether or not a `QPushButton` has the focus. The default button may also play a role.

Comment: @gnogno35 I extended my answer again - this time with buttons. It worked on my side. What OS and window system are you using?

Comment: As I already pointed out, this is not how you automate a UI. Use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms726294.aspx), that's one of its intended purposes.

Comment: @IInspectable I noticed your comment (and even thought a moment to mention it in my answer but forgot about it). This was rather the result of toying exploring how Qt does and does not. Btw. gnogno35 confirmed that [UIAutomation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms726294.aspx) will probably become her/his first choice.

Comment: @gnogno35 Something else, I forgot to mention. The `QString` argument of the `QKeyEvent` is relevant! I found out accidentally when I sent `Qt::Key_A + i` together with `QString(QChar('0' + i))` to `QLineEdit`. Guess what `QLineEdit` inserted... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff I use QCoreApplication::sendEvent because I don't know which widget is focused on. The event is then sent on the main widget (the real application has a layout of 5 or 6 "big sub-widget"). But I can't manage push and toggle buttons with SPACE keypress ... UI automation to follow ...

Comment: @Scheff thanx for your help

Comment: @gnogno35 The widget which is focused can be retrieved by [`QApplication::focusWidget()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#focusWidget). You can set the focus programmatically as well. As I found out in my samples (at least in X11), the focus doesn't seem to play a role (so much) when posting events to a specific widget. Btw. your choice of UIAutomation let me think you're on MS Windows. At least, it is _less_ portable than your original approach. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff UI automation seems to be out of Qt standard distrib :-( I used QApplication::focusWidget() to send an event to but this does not simulate a click on widgets ...

Comment: @gnogno35 [UIAutomation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms726294.aspx) is a framework from Microsoft - it has nothing to do with Qt. (The link is on MSDN.) Meanwhile I compiled the last version of my sample code again with VS2013 and Qt for WinAPI (answer extended) - it behaved exactly like before. Did you try my code on your side?

Comment: @Scheff yes I tryied some parts of your code (and all yous advices ;-) ). Always have the SPACE keypress problem but have some ideas to check. A question about your code : I read in the Qt documentation that the events should be allocated on the stack and you allocate them in the heap, what about deallocation ? Done by postEvent ? It would explain why my application crashes when I use postEvent with events on stack ... or not.

Comment: @gnugnu35 This is _the_ difference between `sendEvent()` and [`postEvent()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent). The latter requires that: _The event must be allocated on the heap since the post event queue will take ownership of the event and delete it once it has been posted. It is not safe to access the event after it has been posted._ (cited from linked doc.)

Comment: @gnugnu35 Btw. replacing `sendEvent()` with `postEvent()` was the key factor which made my solution working. I believe that marshalling synthetic events over event loop (which probably happens in `postEvent()` but definitely not in `sendEvent()`) makes them indistinguishable from "real" events (at least to a certain degree).

Comment: I finally replaced my sendEvent with postEvent ... works fine. Thanx.

Comment: @gnogno35 Nice to hear. I wouldn't deny when you honor my effort with an "answer accepted" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simulating keypresses seems unnecessary. The receiver handles three commands:

- If the main window is inactive, it is activated, and if no widget has focus, the first widget to get it is explicitly focused, and the command ignored.
- `NEXT_FOCUS`: moves focus to the next item in the focus chain (as Tab would)
- `PREVIOUS_FOCUS`: moves focus to the previous item in the focus chain (as Shift-Tab would)
- `CLICK`: invokes the focused widget's `click()` method - all of Qt's buttons support it, since it's in their base `QAbstractButton` class.

Thus, something like the below should do the trick, and you don't need to emulate the keyboard - especially that it's not guaranteed at all that the particular keys you mention have the effects you expect - the behavior is plaform-specific, and may be even theme-specific. E.g. on OS X, the native behavior is for spacebar to have no effects, because buttons are not focusable.

```
enum Command {
   NEXT_FOCUS,      // focus next clickable widget
   PREVIOUS_FOCUS,  // focus previous clickable widget
   FOCUS,           // focus current clickable widget, or next one if none
   CLICK            // like FOCUS, but also clicks the widget
};

bool executeCommand(QWidget *window, Command command) {
   Q_ASSERT(window && window->isWindow());
   using Method = bool (QWidget::*)(bool);
   struct Helper : QWidget {
      static Method get_focusNextPrevChild() { return &Helper::focusNextPrevChild; }
   };
   static Method const focusNextPrevChild = Helper::get_focusNextPrevChild();

   if (!window->isActiveWindow()) {
      window->activateWindow();
      command = FOCUS;
   }

   for (QWidget *focused = nullptr;;) {
      if (command == NEXT_FOCUS) {
         if (!(window->*focusNextPrevChild)(true)) return false;
      } else if (command == PREVIOUS_FOCUS) {
         if (!(window->*focusNextPrevChild)(false)) return false;
      }
      auto *newFocused = window->focusWidget();
      if (!newFocused) return false;
      if (focused && focused == newFocused)
         return false;  // no eligible widgets found
      else if (!focused)
         focused = newFocused;
      auto *newMetaObject = newFocused->metaObject();
      int const clickIdx = newMetaObject->indexOfMethod("click()");
      if (clickIdx >= 0)
         return command == FOCUS || newMetaObject->method(clickIdx).invoke(focused);
      if (command != NEXT_FOCUS && command != PREVIOUS_FOCUS)
         command = NEXT_FOCUS;  // iterate over widgets till a clickable one is found
   }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting approach ... I'll give it a try. The SPACE bar behaviour could be solved :-)

Comment: @ Kuba Ober Tested : I added a test on visible or not (the real HMI is made of several panels of which only one is visible). A test on "clickable" should be fine but doesn't exist ... Maybe the use of the whatThis property could solve. Anyway, the main problem is that there is no "decoration" around the focused button. Don't know why ...

Comment: @ Kuba Ober ... it works once one widget has been focused explicitly